# How to get a list from firestore using where clause

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `dart` to query my collection in firestore in order to get a list of strings. Here's the firestore structure:

[image: FireStore List]

Here's my code:

```
  Future getIngredients() async {
        var firestore = Firestore.instance;
        List<String> ingredients = new List<String>();
        // this will return exactly one document every time. 
        CollectionReference col = firestore.collection("ingredients");
        Query query = col.where('name', isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase());
    // How do I retrieve the ingredient list?
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's what I did after following [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore/versions/0.8.2+3) link.

```
Future getIngredients() async {

    var list = [];
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('ingredients')
        .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase())
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) =>
        data.documents.forEach((doc) => list.add(doc["ingredients"])));

       print("First item is" + list[0]);
     return list;
  }
```

However, the list seems to be empty. However, when I do **print(doc["ingredients"])**, I get all the data. What am I doing wrong?

**Second Update**

So I managed to get the data and now I am trying to display it with the following code:

```
new ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 90,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                      return SingleIngredient(
                        ingredient_name: snapshot.data[index].data["ingredients"],

                      );


                  });
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'. I/flutter
>   (31722): Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' I/flutter (31722):
>   Tried calling: length

Any ideas how to iterate through the ingredient list?

Comment: Please refer the [example](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-) given here.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: doc["ingredients"] will return list. And you are trying to add that list to first item of your list. That's why it's not working!

Comment: How do I return a list then? What confuses me is the foreach syntax. That's why I though I had to add each item to my list

Comment: It's already given [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore/versions/0.8.2+3) under _Binding a CollectionReference to a ListView_ section.

Comment: But I want to return a list and then simply do snapshot.data[index], since this will return the list items right?

Comment: Hey man @bangbang, did you manage to get it working? Having the same problem here.

Comment: If you are trying to get the count here: `itemCount: snapshot.data.length`, should it be `itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length`?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you forgot to call `setState` after updating the List in the class.

```dart
Future getIngredients() async {
  var list = [];
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('ingredients')
      .where("name", isEqualTo: widget.dish_name.toString().toLowerCase())
      .get()
      .then((data) =>
          data.docs.forEach((doc) {
            setState(() {
              list.add(doc['ingredients']);
            });
          }));
}
```